# Smooth scrolling with anchors on Sharepoint site

Tags: 2013, jquery

I have a SharePoint 2013 site which I am trying to include smooth scrolling using jQuery.

There is a menu which becomes sticky after scrolling past, and each menu item should highlight as it goes past each section.
I have got that part to work, but the scrolling to each section seems to jump about.

I know that you have to `#s4-workspace` rather than `html, body`, but it still just seems a very random position to scroll to.

See me JS code below:

```
  mpjQ('a[href*=#]').bind("click", function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();


    mpjQ(document).off("scroll");

    mpjQ('a').each(function () {
        mpjQ(this).removeClass('active');
    })
    mpjQ(this).addClass('active');

    var target = this.hash,
        menu = target;
    mpjQtarget = mpjQ(target);
   mpjQ('#s4-workspace').stop().animate({
        'scrollTop': mpjQtarget.offset().top+2
    }, 600, 'swing', function () {
        window.location.hash = target;
        mpjQ(document).on("scroll", onScroll);
    });

  // Apply sticky menu
  var window_top = mpjQ("s4-workspace").scrollTop();
  var offset = mpjQ('#sticky-anchor').offset();
  var div_top = offset.top; 

  if (window_top > div_top) {
    mpjQ('#sticky').addClass('stick');
    mpjQ('#globalNavBox').addClass('stick-to-menu');
    //    mpjQ('li a[href="#unit1"]').addClass('active');
  }

  else {
    mpjQ('#sticky').removeClass('stick');
    //mpjQ('li a[href^="#"]').removeClass('active');
    mpjQ('#globalNavBox').removeClass('stick-to-menu');
    //  mpjQ('li a[href="#unit1"]').removeClass('active');
  }

  mpjQ('#s4-workspace').on("scroll", onScroll);

})

function onScroll(event){


// Change active class
var scrollPos = mpjQ(document).scrollTop();
mpjQ('.nav li a').each(function () {
    var currLink = mpjQ(this);
    var refElement = mpjQ(currLink.attr("href"));
    if (refElement.position().top <= scrollPos && refElement.position().top + refElement.height() > scrollPos) {
        mpjQ('.nav li a').removeClass("active");
        currLink.addClass("active");
    }
    else {
        currLink.removeClass("active");
    }
});


}
```

I am using mpjQ instead of $ to avoid any jquery conflicts.

Any pointers why this might be going wrong would be very helpful.